# How to create a Temperature by Year line graph, by Month, in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping

I have wrangled the data exported from the website into a long data frame, going from this:
[image]

to this:
[image]

My code:

```
# Birmingham, AL Climate Data from 1896-2024

#Read the data file for temperature
bhamTemp <- read.csv("/Users/.../Documents/DataAnalysisFun/Temperature_BirminghamAL_1896-2024.csv")


library(tidyr)

# Wrangle the data into the correct format
bhamTempMonths <- bhamTemp %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = 'X1':'X12',
    names_to = "Month",
    values_to = "Temperature"
  )

library(ggplot2)

# Create line plots for each month across time
ggplot(data=bhamTempMonths, aes(x=Year, y=Temperature, color=Month)) +
  geom_line()
```

Is producing a graph that looks like this:
[image]

I do not understand how to get the graph to show the scatterplot, but also show the average monthly temperature across years. I have tried creating an average variable, but I am completely lost. I have not touched R in 4 years and have forgotten everything.

Thank you for any help or guidance.

Comment: It looks like your `bhamTempMonths$Temperature` column is `character` and not `numeric`. This most likely occurred during your pivot. Please share the output from `dput(head(bhamTemp))` into a [code block]. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not share images of data for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

Comment: BDizzle, please consider going back to your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9466004/bdizzle?tab=questions) and accepting answers by clicking on the check-mark; this indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, but it's considered the "norm" on Stack sites. Thank you!